# WPF nested Expanders binding to ListBoxItem not working

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I was trying to use `Expander` with **one opened at a time**. I got a code from the [MSDN Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2988ae8-e7b8-4a62-a34f-b851aaf13886#expander_list).

```xml
<ListBox>
    <!-- all styles and templates-->
    <Expander Header="One"><!-- some content --></Expander>
    <Expander Header="Two"><!-- some other content --></Expander>
</ListBox>
```

It is **working fine**. *Only one of the above Expander will be open at a Time*.

But if I try a nested Expanders, lower Expanders **doesn't open and close as desired** as above code. Meaning if I add content to **Expander "Two"** like below

```xml
<Expander Header="Two">
    <ListBox>
        <!-- same styles and templates as above-->
        <Expander Header="Sub-One"><!-- some content --></Expander>
        <Expander Header="Sub-Two"><!-- some other content --></Expander>
    </ListBox>
</Expander>
```

The Expanders "Sub-One" and "Sub-Two" are **some how linked to same** `ListBoxItem` to which Expander "Two" is attached

[image: Expanders "Sub-One" and "Sub-Two" getting expanded and collapsed at same time]

I guess I need to make some change in the binding but couldn't do it.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
        Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
</Style>
```

Any guidance will be of great help.
*Note:- Few things which I tried*

  - Checked parents of the Expander in the code, only ListBox is coming and there was no ListBoxItem in the hierachy
  - Tried Adding different values to AncestorLevel, no value except 1 works
  - Was thinking of Binding to ListBox SelectedIndex, this also I cannot make it work as was unable to think of Converting SelectedIndex to IsExpandable, even if I use converters

Answer (score 0):

For the style you could try Binding to the Selector.IsSelected attached property as seen here [MSDN Selector.IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.isselected.aspx)